# Can you give me an example of a real function with a behavior like this

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm searching for a real function $f:\bigl[0,\infty\bigr)\to\mathbb{R}$ which is:

1. $\mathcal C^{\hspace{0.45mm}\infty}$ for simplicity;
2. $f(0)=0$
3. $f''(x)<0$ in the interval $\bigl[0,x_{M}\bigr]$ where $x_{M}$ is a maximum of $f$
4. $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\alpha>0$ but its behavior is like $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$, so $f$ is oscillating around $\alpha$

Comment: I've answered your question, but what is the context behind your question?

Comment: well, given a bounded region I'm using this function to say that the amount of resources which grows in that region is limited but it oscillates around its limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the cosine Fresnel integral $C(x)=\int_0^x\cos t^2\,dt$ is what you need:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are elementary possibilities, too:
$$2 \alpha \left(\frac{1}{e^{-\beta x}+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1 +\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)$$

Plot with $\alpha=1,\beta=1$:

[image]

Plot with $\alpha=1/2,\beta=2$:

[image]

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the maximum $x_M$ occurs at the very first peak; the second peak looks just about as high, so couldn't it be ever so slightly higher (in which case the second derivative is no longer negative on the entire interval $[0,x_M]$)?

Comment: That can be fixed by making the sigmoid factor steeper, see edit. (I interpreted your question as meaning a local maximum)

Comment: Looks good to me! If you like, I'll delete my earlier comment (and this one). But some readers might find it instructive to look at the edit history to see what we're talking about. Just ping me if you think it's better to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

$$ f(x)=\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1}-e^{-x}+1-\sin 1$$

The first is just $\frac{\sin x}x$ translated and dominates the behaviou as $x\to \infty$. The translation causes the global maximum to move to the right by $1$ unit.
The exponential term corrects a problem that $f''$ is negative near $0$ (while not significantly affecting the extrema); together with the correction terms that ensure $f(0)=0$, it also pushes the limit as $x\to \infty $ up.